# preg_split regex doesn't work right

Tags: php, regex, preg-split

Have to split a text by an dynamic id f.e.

My regex:

```
$content = preg_split('/<span id="more-[1-9]+"><\/span>/i', get_the_content('more'));
```

Unfortunately sometimes it works, sometimes not:

```
<span id="more-1237"></span> -> it works

<span id="more-1029"></span> -> not working
```

whats wrong, thanks for help

Comment: Can you paste some examples for your ids and the content you want to parse?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your second example has a zero in the digits after `more-`, which your regex won't match. You need something like:

```
$content = preg_split('/<span id="more-[0-9]+"><\/span>/i', get_the_content('more'));
```

Note the change from `[1-9]` to `[0-9]`.